# כדי ביקור\כדי שחיטה

Tags: chulin-tractate

In Chulin 32a, there is an argument between Tana Kama and Rabbi Shimon regarding what happens if you break in the middle of Shechita. If the break is too long, the Shechita is Pasul. According to Tana Kama, you cannot break more than "Kedei Shechita." According to Rabbi Shimon, it's "Kedei Bikur." Which is longer?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dani and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!